# window photo viewer cant open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or is too large

Tags: c#, file-upload

i am using c# to upload a file from one server to another server . file is uploaded successfully but when i am trying to open the file it says "it cant be open because it may be damaged, corrupted."

Here is my code

```
 /*Creating the WebRequest object using the URL of SaveFile.aspx.*/
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest =
    (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create
    ("http://localhost:19889/SaveFiles/SaveFile.aspx");
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            /*Assigning the content type from the FileUpload control.*/
            webRequest.ContentType = pic.ContentType ;
            /*Creating the Header object.*/
            System.Net.WebHeaderCollection headers = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection();
            headers.Add("FileName", pic.FileName);
            /*Adding the header to the WebRequest object.*/
            webRequest.Headers = headers;
            var fileByte = new byte[pic.ContentLength];
            /*Getting the request stream by making use of the GetRequestStream method of WebRequest object.*/
            using (System.IO.Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())//Filling request stream with image stream. 
            {
                /*Writing the FileUpload content to the request stream.*/
                stream.Write(fileByte, 0, pic.ContentLength);
            }
            /*Creating a WebResponse object by calling the GetResponse method of WebRequest object.*/
            using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse webResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                /*Retrieving the response stream from the WebResponse object by calling the GetResponseStream method.*/
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                   // lblMessage.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

and this is code of savefile.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            /*Retrieving the file name from the headers in the request. */
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), Request.Headers["FileName"].ToString());
            using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
            {
                /*Getting stream from the Request object.*/
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = Request.InputStream)
                {
                    int byteStreamLength = (int)stream.Length;
                    byte[] byteStream = new byte[byteStreamLength];
                    /*Reading the stream to a byte array.*/
                    stream.Read(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
                    /*Writing the byte array to the harddisk.*/
                    fileStream.Write(byteStream, 0, byteStreamLength);
                }
            }
            Response.Clear();
            /*Writing the status to the response.*/
            Response.Write("File successfully saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /*Writing the error message to the response stream.*/
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then show the relevant code of `SaveFile.aspx`.

Comment: I've updated the question with savefile.aspx code

Comment: So, did you do a comparison of the files? Are they equal in size? Do they contain the same contents? You don't appear to be reading `pic` anywhere, so you're posting an array of all zeroes.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: @ CodeCaster No i can't use the pic anywhere beacause these are two different solution . and they have same content

Comment: You're not populating `fileByte` with the actual contents of the file. The array will be all zeroes. Read the file into the array. You could've seen this by opening the file.

Comment: No its not null anywhere . Image is getting saved. actually when i am doing the same using asp control i.e FileUpload in place of pic it works fine but in case of mvc i mean when i am using pic it gets corrupted.

Comment: In the upper code block you are **not reading the file**. You are initializing an array of `new byte[pic.ContentLength]` and then **not filling it**. You are posting an array of all zeros. You can see this by inspecting this file after uploading it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'd tried but problem still exist . do you have any solution for this?